# Copying text from excel to word keeps failing

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have been trying to copy text from an Excel document to a Word document using a VBA macro - however it keeps failing at seemingly random points and it spits out one of two different error messages. There seems to be no rhyme or reason as to where it will fail or what error message it will give me.

Firstly, this is a sample Excel spreadsheet that I am using:
[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

This is what the Word document looks like when the macro is run:
[image: Word Export]

Sometimes it will fail with the following error message - but when you try and debug it - it doesn't actually show a line where the failure is occuring:

[image: First Error Message]

At other times - it will fail with the following error message. When it fails with this message - you can debug it and it shows that it fails on one of the four **.Paste** lines:

[image: Second Error Message]

Finally, here is my VBA macro:

```
Sub CopyFromExcelToWordUsingCopyPaste()

    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim myIndex As Integer
    Dim questionNumber As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' this figures out the last used row by counting backwards (up) from the bottom until it finds some data
    questionNumber = 1
   
     ' create a new word application and word document
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wrdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wrdApp Is Nothing Then
        Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    wrdApp.Visible = True
    
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add ' create a new document
        
    ' insert the question and response data
    For myIndex = 2 To lastRow
        With wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection
            ' insert the question data
            .TypeText questionNumber & ". "
            Range("A" & myIndex).Copy
            .Paste
            
           ' insert response A, B and C data
            .TypeText "a) "
            Range("B" & myIndex).Copy
            .Paste
            .TypeText "b) "
            Range("C" & myIndex).Copy
            .Paste
            .TypeText "c) "
            Range("D" & myIndex).Copy
            .Paste
            
            ' insert a new paragraph and increment to the next question
            .TypeParagraph
            questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
        End With
    Next
    
    ' Save the word document into the WordExport Folder
    wrdDoc.SaveAs "c:\Data\testDocument.docx", FileFormat:=12 'wdFormatXMLDocument
    wrdDoc.Close ' close the document
    
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing
    Set wrdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

If anyone could give some help as to why this keeps failing - it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On what line(s) do the errors occur?

Comment: Good question - I'll update my original post however it either fails on one of the four .Paste commands (but you never know which one) -or- it fails without showing where it fails.

Comment: I'd suggest you litter the code with debug.print 1, debug.print 2 etc. When it fails you'll know the last print statement executed. From there you fine-tune the debugging with breakpoints and single-step

Comment: In my case it works fine.

Comment: Try putting a DoEvents command at the end of your loop and before it goes back to get the next question cell. The symptoms you report sound like the clipboard is possibly getting corrupted because the code can issue a new copy/paste command before the previous event has finished.

Comment: @StureS The main problem is that it will fail at different points each time I run the macro. I am using the exact same spreadsheet data each time I run it. Sometimes it will make it all the way to Question 50 before failing, sometimes it will make it to question 2 and the fail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RichMichaels. I inserted a DoEvents command in the line just above the **End With** line. Unfortunately the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question but it is an alternative way to transfer the data from Excel to Word instead of copy and paste.

```
...
With wrdDoc.Content
    ' insert the question data
    .InsertAfter questionNumber & ". " & Range("A" & myIndex) & vbCr
    
    ' insert response A, B and C data
    .InsertAfter "a) " & Range("B" & myIndex) & vbCr
    .InsertAfter "b) " & Range("C" & myIndex) & vbCr
    .InsertAfter "c) " & Range("D" & myIndex) & vbCr
    
    ' insert a new paragraph and increment to the next question
    .InsertAfter vbCr
    questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
End With
...
```

**Update:** Again, this doesn't answer your question, but you could copy the whole range in one and then manipulate the data in Word.

```
...
' copy the question and response data
Range("A2:D" & lastRow).Copy

' paste to Word as a table
wrdDoc.Content.Paste

With wrdDoc.Tables(1)
    ' align table text left
    .Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
    
    ' loop through table rows
    For questionNumber = 1 To .Rows.Count
        With .Rows(questionNumber)
            ' insert question number
            .Cells(1).Range.InsertBefore questionNumber & ". "
            
            ' insert response letters
            .Cells(2).Range.InsertBefore "a) "
            .Cells(3).Range.InsertBefore "b) "
            .Cells(4).Range.InsertBefore "c) "
            
            ' insert new line at end of row
            .Cells(4).Range.InsertAfter vbCr

            ' ensure no page break occurs between question/response
            .Range.ParagraphFormat.KeepWithNext = True
            .Cells(4).Range.ParagraphFormat.KeepWithNext = False
        End With
    Next
    
    ' split table into 1 column
    .Range.Cells.Split NumColumns:=1
    
    ' convert table to text
    .ConvertToText Separator:=wdSeparateByParagraphs
End With
...
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that it doesn’t preserve character formatting such as superscript. That’s why the OP is using the clipboard.

Comment: Thanks for the info Sam however need the formatting preserved as I bring the text across into Word.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I didn't think of that.

Comment: I've updated my post with another alternative which does use copy and paste this time.

Comment: This works great Sam! It didn't even cross my mind to bring everything into Word all at once and then to format it from within Word. Well done and thank you very much for the help. If I could ask one more thing - sometimes the question/responses will span two pages. Is there a straight forward way of ensuring that the question will start on a new page if it is spanning two pages?

Comment: Hi Brad. Yes, that's quite straightforward. I've updated the code with 2 additional lines to accomplish this.

Comment: This is just fantastic Sam and I appreciate you taking the time to help out with this - it is just perfect!.